# Is the definition $f(x+1) = x$ a valid function definition? If not, why not?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

I encountered the following informal brainteaser:

> Is the definition $f(x+1) = x$ a valid function definition?
> If not, why not?

Not having much formal training in mathematics,
I figured this was equivalent to $f(x) = x-1$,
but the person who posed the question claimed:

> It isn't a valid function definition,
> because a function by definition has one output for every input.
> If this was a function,
> we would have $f(0+1) = f(1+0) = f(0) = f(1) = 0 = 1$,
> which is a contradiction.
> However, as a relation, it's valid.

I found it hard to follow the logic.
It seems to me that the definition would give $f(0+1) = 0$,
but I don't understand how it gives that $f(1+0) = 1$.
I asked some clarifying questions,
but found myself not much closer to understanding.
They said:

> It's a simple contradiction derived from commutativity actually,
> because $x+1 = 1+x$, then $f(x+1) = f(1+x)$,
> which you might argue isn't how functions work,
> but that's exactly the point of the teaser.

I guess my question is this:
how does the definition of this relation
lead to multiple outputs for one input?

Comment: Either there has been some miscommunication here or the person who posed the question has no idea what they are talking about.

Comment: Why would $f(0+1)=f(0)$?

Comment: Why wouldn't it be? Maybe it'd be clearer if you replaced $x+1$ by $y$. Then we have $f(y)=y-1$. A simple linear function

Comment: "the person who posed the question" Who is that person? We are 8 billions people on this planet, this leaves a lot for possibilities of people talking nonsense. That said, are you sure it is not $f(x+y)=x$, which indeed would be ill-defined?

Comment: This looks like ChapGPT generated nonsense...

Comment: I would say: NO, that is not a valid definition of a function.  You need to do some work, and end up with $f(x) = x-1$, which is a definition of a function (with added explanation about domain and range...)  Even if the two are "equivalent", still only one of them is a definition of a function.

Comment: Complete nonsense. Voting to close, pending an actual link to where this is posted.

Comment: @GEdgar I think the context is conditional. "If f were to be a function... would this be a valid definition?" Kind of like "if there were a real number solution to $x^2+1=0$ what is the solution set?". It's not nonsensical to ask the latter

Comment: Yes: "What are the function(s) $f$ satisfying $f(x+1)=x$?" is a good question.  It is a "functional equation" not a "function definition".

Answer (score 1):

To define a function, we must also specify its domain and codomain.

So here we could for example define $f: [0,10] \to  \mathbb R$ by $f(x+1)=x$.

The above definition says that $f$ maps each object (call it $x+1$) in the domain $[0,10]$ to the object $x$ in the codomain $\mathbb R$.

Equivalently, $f$ maps each object (call it $a$) in the domain $[0,10]$ to the object $a-1$ in the codomain $\mathbb R$.

So, equivalently but more conventionally, we'd define $f: [0,10] \to  \mathbb R$ by $f(a)=a-1$.

So yes, the definition you gave is valid, but we must also specify the domain and codomain.

---

I do not understand your quotation from "the person who posed the question".

These are fine:

- $f(0+1) = f(1+0)$;
- $f(0+1) = 0$; and
- $f(0+1) = f(1)$.

But I do not see how

- $f(0+1) = f(0)$; or
- $f(0+1) = 1$.

And in the last quote, I fail to see what the "simple contradiction" is.